# Filtering top n values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
ID   Group Name   Information
1    A            'Info type1'
1    A            'Info type2' 
2    B            'Info type2' 
2    B            'Info type3' 
2    B            'Info type4'
3    A            'Info type2' 
3    A            'Info type5'
3    A            'Info type2'
```

Ultimately, I want to count, how many items have been processed by a specific group and group them by a specific `Info type`.

In a first step I have defined a function to somehow filter the specific `info type`:

```
def checkrejcted(strval):
    if strval == 'Info type5':
        return 'Rejected'
    else:
        return 'Not rejected'
```

In a next step, I have applied this function to the `information` column:

```
dataset['CheckRejected'] = dataset['Information'].apply(checkrejcted)
```

Lastly, I have dropped duplicates, after dropping the `information` column. 
So the dataset looks like:

```
ID   Group Name   CheckRejected
1    A            'Not rejected'
2    B            'Not rejected' 
3    A            'Not rejected'
3    A            'Rejected'
```

I am wondering, whether there is a smarter way to count how often a specific group name occurs and group it based on `Not rejected`, `Rejected`. It can happen, that specific items can have the `information` `Rejected`/`Not rejected` at the same time. This is fine, as I assume that within the countplot this item will be counted for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a map, and fillna with a default non matching action:

```
maps = { "'Info type5'": "'Rejected'" } 
or
maps = { "'Info type1'": "'Not Rejected'",   "'Info type2'": "'Not Rejected'" ,  "'Info type3'": "'Not Rejected'" ,  "'Info type4'": "'Not Rejected'", "'Info type5'": "'Rejected'"  } 

df['Information'].map(maps).fillna('Not Rejected')                                                                                                                                 

0    'Not Rejected'
1    'Not Rejected'
2    'Not Rejected'
3    'Not Rejected'
4    'Not Rejected'
5    'Not Rejected'
6        'Rejected'
7    'Not Rejected'
```

df['CheckRejected'] =  df['Information'].map(maps).fillna("'Not Rejected'")

```
   ID Group Name   Information   CheckRejected
0   1          A  'Info type1'  'Not Rejected'
1   1          A  'Info type2'  'Not Rejected'
2   2          B  'Info type2'  'Not Rejected'
3   2          B  'Info type3'  'Not Rejected'
4   2          B  'Info type4'  'Not Rejected'
5   3          A  'Info type2'  'Not Rejected'
6   3          A  'Info type5'      'Rejected'
7   3          A  'Info type2'  'Not Rejected'
```

df.drop(columns='Information').drop_duplicates()

```
   ID Group Name   CheckRejected
0   1          A  'Not Rejected'
2   2          B  'Not Rejected'
5   3          A  'Not Rejected'
6   3          A      'Rejected'
```

Comment: @RlikeRun Thank you! Check out this site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 and thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you want to **count** rows.
So probably you need:

```
df.groupby(['Group Name', 'Information']).size()
```

For your sample data, the result is the following *Series*:

```
Group Name  Information
A           Info type1     1
            Info type2     3
            Info type5     1
B           Info type2     1
            Info type3     1
            Info type4     1
dtype: int64
```

Its MultiIndex contains the grouping key (both levels)
and the value is just the number of occurrences.

Dropping duplicetes does not do the job, as you loose
the information **how many times** particular combination
occurred.

Or if you want to count only *Rejected* / *Not Rejected* cases then:

- map *Information* column, using your function and creating a new column,
  say *Status*,
- group by *Group Name* and *Status*.

The code to do it is:

```
df['Status'] = df.Information.apply(checkrejcted)
df.groupby(['Group Name', 'Status']).size()
```